# In my ListView control, is there a way for me to GET the index of a clicked item?

Tags: c#, listview

Pretty straight forward question, but I can't find a way to do it.

When a user double clicks an item in my ListView I want to save the index number of the clicked item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a reference to the ListViewItem:

```
listView.Items.IndexOf(listViewItem)
```

Or just access `listView.SelectedIndices` in the Activate event handler -- if your ListView is single-select then there'll be only one index in there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which **ListView** you're using.  All three have a property to get the selected item's index:

For Windows Forms, use [ListView.SelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx)

For WPF, use [ListView.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx)

For Web, use [ListView.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex.aspx)